# error which says TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'vert', what do i do?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

```
data1 = randn(100)
data2 = randn(100)
sns.boxplot(data1,vert=False)
```

the above lines of code give me error below
`TypeError: boxplot(`) got multiple values for keyword argument `'vert'`

(All the required libraries are imported)

My version is 3.6 of Python and I am using `Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook` to execute the code

Comment: `vert` doesn't seem to be a valid keyword for [**`seaborn.boxplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html). I know nothing about `seaborn`. Perhaps you're confusing it with [**`matplotlib.boxplot`**](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html)

Comment: Are you using `seaborn.boxplot()` or `matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot()` ? The latter contains the keyword parameter `vert` -- but the error that was thrown suggests you are using `seaborn.boxplot()` -- and incorrectly -- see doc:https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a seaborn boxplot, the keyword argument you need is `orient`. This has options `"h"` for horizontal, or `"v"` for vertical .

So for your case the solution would simply be `sns.boxplot(data1, orient="h")`.

Seaborn boxplot calls `ax.boxplot` under the hood. Seaborn doesn't accept `vert` as an argument because `vert` is calculated by seaborn from the `orient` argument in `categorical.py` line 457-459, which is then passed to `ax.boxplot`:

```
def draw_boxplot(self, ax, kws):
    """Use matplotlib to draw a boxplot on an Axes."""
    vert = self.orient == "v"
```

If you were to include `vert=False` in `sns.boxlpot(data1, vert=False)` that would essentially be the same as `ax.boxplot(data1, vert=False, vert=False)` which you can't do.

Answer (score 0):

error: boxplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'  for pandas `df.boxplot()` users,

You can solve this by specifying the ***column*** and ***by*** arguments, where **column** is the value you want to analyses boxplot on and **by** is for the groups or categorical values on the x-axis of the boxplot. The documentation [pandas.DataFrame.boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) has more details on other arguments and examples as well.